# Firestore - Python filter by value in a list

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Here, I have data stored in Firestore and I have a key `timeslots` that store JSON list that I would like to filter by string value (e.g. 3 AM (EST), 4 AM (EST)) directly from Firebase. Normally, I can do the following in Python:

```
from google.cloud import firestore

db = firestore.Client()
ref = db.collection('submissions')
submissions = []
for idx, doc in enumerate(ref.stream()):
    submission = doc.to_dict()
    submission['id'] = doc.id
submissions.append(submission)
```

where `submissions` is a list that look something like follows:

```
[{'submission_date': DatetimeWithNanoseconds(2020, 7, 10, 20, 58, 9, 330598, tzinfo=<UTC>),
  'title': 'Testing submission',
  'authors': ['Mr. A', 'Mr. B'],
  'timeslots': ['3 AM (EST)', '4 AM (EST)'],
  'abstract': 'No abstract here',
  'id': '12345'},
 {'submission_date': DatetimeWithNanoseconds(2020, 7, 10, 20, 58, 9, 330598, tzinfo=<UTC>),
  'title': 'Testing submission 2',
  'authors': ['Mr. C', 'Mr. D'],
  'timeslots': ['4 AM (EST)', '5 AM (EST)'],
  'abstract': 'No abstract here too',
  'id': '123456'},
  ...
 ]
```

Generally, I do the following to filter time `== 3 AM (EST)` in this case:

```
submissions_filtered = [
    submission for submission in submissions
    if '3 AM (EST)' in submission.get('timeslots', '')
]
```

I'm not sure if I can do it directly from Firestore `stream` (or something else). If someone knows, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to filter documents based on some string in an array type field, you can use an "array-contains" query as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#python_6).

```
ref = db.collection('submissions').where('timeslots', 'array_contains', '3 AM (EST)')
```

Comment: NVM, I got this error: "ValueError: Operator string 'array-contains' is invalid. Valid choices are: <, <=, ==, >, >=, array_contains, array_contains_any, in."

Comment: OK, so use `array_contains` instead.